# Change sda2 to sda1

Tags: partitioning, disk

I had two partitions and I recently deleted sda1 and moved sda2(Ubuntu) to where sda1 was located and made it use the whole disk, sda2 is still sda2 though and I want to make it show as sda1 instead.

I've got a Ubuntu Live USB which is where I installed Ubuntu from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partition-number is determined by the partition-table entry. Deleting the first partition, in fact means to delete the first partition-table entry. the remaining second partition is still defined by the second partition-table entry, thus it's number is still `2`.

There is not really a need to change that, if your partition is defined by the first or second partition-table entry does not matter, in real life you will rarely see your partition number, there is no impact on performance. Reordering your partition-table entries comes with some risk, you may accidentally enter wrong commands.

There is a chance that grub will be broken (since grub uses UUID to find correct partitions I wouldn't expect that, but be prepared to eventually have to reinstall grub).

If you've made any changes to `/etc/fstab` and use `/dev/sda2` instead of UUID, you'll have to change that as well.

I recommend not to do this change, there is no advantage you could gather.

---

If you really inist in doing that change, here we go:

Use your installer-USB to `Try without installing` and perform the action from this session, your partition has to be unmounted!

Recheck the correct drive with `lsblk -f` to see if `/dev/sda` is still the correct drive, it may or may not change when booted from installer. You'll have to adapt the devicename in the following commands depending on the output you got from the `lsblk`-command.

Create a copy of the partition-table:

```
~$ sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sdatable
```

The result looks like this:

```
~$ cat sdatable
label: gpt
label-id: CAEC9287-6E64-48BD-8223-B951EE4C7345
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 625142414
sector-size: 512

/dev/sda2 : start=        2048, size=   625131520, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=917D415A-7E8F-C74E-8D72-1259A7C02ED6, name="archiv"
```

Now edit only the start of the last line from `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/sda1`, leave anything else as it is. I used `nano` to do this. The last line should now look like this:

```
/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=   625131520, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=917D415A-7E8F-C74E-8D72-1259A7C02ED6, name="archiv"
```

In the next step load the altered copy of the partition-table:

```
~$ sudo sfdisk --force /dev/sda < sdatable
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK

Disk /dev/sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HTS54503
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CAEC9287-6E64-48BD-8223-B951EE4C7345

Old situation:

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda2   2048 625133567 625131520 298.1G Linux filesystem

>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: CAEC9287-6E64-48BD-8223-B951EE4C7345).
/dev/sda1: Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 298.1 GiB.
Partition #1 contains a ext4 signature.
/dev/sda2: Done.

New situation:
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CAEC9287-6E64-48BD-8223-B951EE4C7345

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 625133567 625131520 298.1G Linux filesystem

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Rechecking with `lsblk` gives as expected

```
~$ lsblk -f | grep sda
sda                                                                                        
└─sda1 ext4     1.0   archiv           57d76d02-deb6-47cf-bb2d-5da748f1cc38
```

Done. Do it on your own risk!

Comment: Often required reinstall of grub and anyplace else where device order like /dev/sda2 is used must be changed. Not as big of an issue as years ago before many entries changed to use UUIDs  which rarely get changed.

Comment: Good in-depth answer as to why and how it could be changed, but I like the advise of the other answer to not bother as an end user.

Comment: @vanadium That's fine. As a matter of fact, I'd also recommend to leave it as it is. There is always the chance to mess things up using fdisk or gdisk without deeper knowledge and experience.

Comment: @mook765 Would be good to include that in your answer at the start, later on explaining how it works and what the user can do if he insists changing the number. Good information!

Comment: "Nothing to do. Ordering is correct already. Failed to fix partitions order" :/

Comment: Just changed it with help from a Unix & Linux post

Comment: @xproot Since my previous idea did not work, I edited my answer to provide a working solution. I really tried this with one of my disks which had a single partition on it and change from sda1 to sda2 and then back to sda1. Works nicely and is not too much of commands to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "change" the number the partition has, as those are assigned when the partition is created. If you really wanted your sda2 to be sda1, then you could delete the sda2 partition, and create a new one which will be called sda1. I would certainly not recommend that however. In the grand scheme of things, the partition's number wouldn't affect anything with your system's performance or functioning, so you should be fine.

Comment: I guess you're right, I just got bothered by the number being 2 instead of 1.