# Where are the partition names /dev/sdx mapped onto the actual partitions?

Tags: partitioning, disk

I rearranged my disk partitions, figuring that I could account for the changes by modifying the files used by **grub**. I'm now trying to understand what actually happened.  The oddest thing is that **gparted** now reports that **/dev/sd4** is immediately followed by **/dev/sd9**. I'd like to understand how the **dev** names are mapped into the actual disk partitions, since they clearly are not consecutive, If I can understand that, I should be able to make the necessary repairs.

Here is some more information,following oldfred's suggestion:

```
root@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/home/pwa# parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name              
            Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32           EFI system 
partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB                  Microsoft 
reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   157GB   156GB   ntfs            Basic data 
partition          msftdata
 4      171GB   172GB   599MB   ntfs                              
            hidden, diag
 9      172GB   486GB   315GB   ext4            Kubuntu 21.10
 5      567GB   867GB   300GB   ext4
 6      867GB   870GB   3000MB  linux-swap(v1)                    
            swap
 7      986GB   987GB   1028MB  ntfs            Basic data 
partition          hidden, diag
 8      987GB   1000GB  12.8GB  ntfs            Basic data 
partition          hidden, msftdata


    root@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/home/pwa# lsblk -e 7 -o 
    name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint
    NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL            PARTLABEL            
            MOUNTPOINT
    sda           931.5G                                              
            
    ├─sda1 vfat     260M 112.1M                  EFI system partition 
            /boot/efi
    ├─sda2           16M                         Microsoft reserved 
    partition 
    ├─sda3 ntfs   145.5G  71.6G Windows          Basic data partition 
            /media/pwa/Windows2
    ├─sda4 ntfs     571M                                              
            
    ├─sda5 ext4   279.4G 186.8G                                       
            /
    ├─sda6 swap     2.8G                                              
            [SWAP]
    ├─sda7 ntfs     980M        Windows RE tools Basic data partition 
            
    ├─sda8 ntfs    11.9G        RECOVERY         Basic data partition 
            
    └─sda9 ext4     293G                         Kubuntu 21.10        
            
    sr0            1024M                                              
            
    root@HP-Pavilion-Laptop-17-ar0xx:/home/pwa#
```

Comment: When looking at partitions on a drive, they do not have to be in a specific order on the drive. And changing order can create lots of issues.  So if your created a new sda9 partition well after sda8 was created but from a shrink of sda4 that would be normal. Best not to try to change partition order. Post this: `sudo parted -l`  and `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint`

Comment: I've augmented my description of the problem with the information you suggested, but I couldn't get it to display cleanly, even using the <blockquote> tag.

Comment: Is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1320631/590937) helpful?

Comment: Changed to Code and a bit better, but two lines, where normally you have to scroll right to see full line. Do you then have two installs, one sda4 & other sda9? Is that what you wanted? I normally have multiple installs per drive as one main working install, and another for experimenting with where I do not want to corrupt main working install.

Comment: I just found out about the use of ``` to enclose code. I've used it to reformat the post.

Comment: I was trying to update Kubuntu to a better version, either 20.04.3 or 21.10, but I didn't want to lose the partition containing the 20.04 Kubuntu.  So I scrounged around to create space for a new partition to contain 20.04.3. That new space was partition 5.